# Hole pattern appears when in sculpt mode

Tags: 3d-view, sculpting, sculpt

I was following along making the Blender Guru Donut® when I found that when I switch to sculpting mode a pattern of holes appear on my icing. I thought it couldnt hurt, maybe it was just for reference or something. But when I was done pulling arround the mesh (and thus some holes) and switched back to layout you could indeed see some artifacts of the holes in the form of spikes, and now my delicious donut is totally ruined.
Im guessing this could have to do with some setting being turned on/off? Can anyone give any help?

Edit: Yes thank you Rjg, that does indeed solve it

[image: Holes]

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151412/why-are-there-hexagonal-holes-in-my-donut