# Why are there hexagonal holes in my donut?

Tags: modeling

I'm currently making a donut using blender gurus tutorial. I have no idea why, but there are holes in my icing. Does anyone know what could be causing it? Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: There's also this Q&A of the same problem. You can try his solution as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151044/why-are-there-holes-in-the-icing

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the exact same problem when trying to follow the tutorials. It seems like Andrew unhides some vertices in the icing at one point but forgot to show it.

If you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> before applying the modifiers, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you already edited the donut, and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> , and you can't go back, you can do this.

Go to Sculpting, press *Grab* (the yellow circle one) and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking and holding on the holes until it's gone.